# The points of intersection with the coordinate planes.

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus

(a)Find the parametric equations for the line through (2,4,6) that is perpendicular to the plane $x-y+3z = 7$.

(b)In what points does this line intersect the coordinate planes.

For part (a) my answer was:  $ x = 2 + t, y = 4 -t, z = 6 + 3t $.

For part (b), I know how to find the intersection of the given line with the given plane, by plugging the values of x,y & z that I got in part(a) in the above plane equation and finding the value of t, then I can plug in the value of t in part (a)to find the intersection of the given line with the given plane.

**But how can I find the points of intersection of this line with the coordinate planes?**

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: For example, the $xy-$plane is $z=0$.

Comment: yes I know this information but then what @stevengregory

Comment: Then you solve $z=0$ for $t$ ($t = -\frac 12$) and use that to compute the values of $x$ and $y$. The intersection will be $(2-\frac 12,4 + \frac 12,0)$.

Comment: @stevengregory I could not understand what you wrote.......could you please write it in the answer zone in a bit more details ?